# proof that the expression is Real for any $z$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Please help me with this problem, I'm
clueless here.

$\ \ \ \ (\bar{z}+1-2i)^{1985} + (\bar{z}+1+2i)^{1985}$

$\ \ \ \ $proof that the expression is Real for any $z$

Comment: I'm almost sure one of the $\bar{z}$ should be a $z$.

Comment: Im not wrong here, unless the papers are wrong.

Comment: In that case, try $z = -(1+2i)$ to see that somebody made a mistake.

Comment: @shir The papers are wrong, and Daniel's example proves this. BTW, what papers?

Comment: okay then. thanks.
In that case, I dont think I have a problem with this question.